# UK Tier 2 Visa Extension Under 'Experienced Rate Salary' vs 'New Entrant Rate Salary'

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas, uk-visa

I have been issued 2 years Tier 2 (formerly work permit) visa and I will need to extend my visa next year. Now, if I apply for maximum possible extension, it will take my total Tier 2 stay beyond 3 years 1 month therefore I need to apply under experienced rate salary (according to [Immigration Rules Appendix J](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-j-codes-of-practice-for-skilled-work) => Appropriate salary rates paragraph 14).

My query is can I apply for just one more year under 'new entrant rate' which will make my total stay in Tier 2, current 2 years + 1 year = 3 years?

Comment: Inquire to see if you can request a Tier 2 visa for a specific period of time. Some visas have locked times or situational rules in place, but many are flexible. I'm just not sure how flexible a Tier 2 visa is in this regards.